# parities of power permutations in finite fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, galois-theory, finite-fields, permutation-cycles

I am searching the parities (or sign) of the power permutations $x^k$ in $GF(2^n)$ for some $n$ and we need $gcd(k,2^n-1) = 1$ to be permutation.

I will use them in S-boxes in cryptographic algorithms, so I need small degrees permutations. The degrees of this permutations are nothing but Hamming weight of $k$. i.e. the number of 1's of the number, in binary notation of $k$. As an example $x^3$ is quadratic, $x^7$ is cubic etc.

OK, then I compile some codes and realize all quadratic permutations have parity even in $GF(2^{4m})$ for some int $m$.

In the rest of finite fields, so in $GF(2^{4m+1}),GF(2^{4m+2}),GF(2^{4m+3})$, I find quadratic and odd permutations.

Is there a mathematics behind this, i am asking since i could not see it, although it seems so. And if you show me a way, it will be great.

Comment: Curious! The only thought I have right away is that for low odd values of $n$ the weight two (i.e. quadratic) choice $k=3$ leads to an odd permutation for $n=1,3,5,7,9,11$ (unless I made a mistake). Then, of course, the other weight two choice $k=9$ leads to an even permutation because it is the square of the previous permutation. I don't know how much ground this covers. Another approach may be better :-)

Comment: Yes you are right @Jyrki Lahtonen. In $GF(2^n)$, so far until $n=120$, $x^3$ (quadratic) has always odd parity for $n$ of the form $n=2m+1$. and $x^5$ (also quadratic), for $n$ of the form $n=4m+2$.